# Caesar Cipher - spaces and other characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, caesar-cipher

I have created a Caesar Cipher code below but I want the returned string to include spaces and other characters.  I've tried regex but this does not seem to solve the problem or maybe i'm not using it right, I'm not too sure.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

```js
function caesarCipher(str, n) {
  let newStr = '';
  let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
  let regex = /[a-z]/

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].match(regex) === false) {
      newStr += str[i]
      continue;
    }
    let currentIndex = alphabet.indexOf(str[i]);
    let newIndex = currentIndex + n;
    newStr += alphabet[newIndex];
  }
  return newStr
}

console.log(caesarCipher('ebiil tloia!', 3)) //should return hello world! but returns hellocworldc
```

Comment: caesarCipher takes 2 arguments, not 1

Comment: It doesn't return `hellocworldc`. It returns an indefinite amount of `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegExp.test` returns a boolean, `String.match` returns an array. This line:

```
if (str[i].match(regex) === false) {
```

should be

```
if (regex.test(str[i]) === false) {
```

This should catch any value that's not a lowercase letter (spaces, punctuation, etc) - If you want to encode uppercase too, add the `i` flag at the end of the regex: `/[a-z]/i`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to pass the shift (3) to the function. Secondly, since there are no spaces in `alphabet`, you need to add a test:

```js
function caesarCipher(str, n) {
  let newStr = '';
  let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
  let regex = /[a-z]/

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].match(regex) === false) {
      newStr += str[i]
    }
    let currentIndex = alphabet.indexOf(str[i]);
    if (!(currentIndex + 1)) {
      newStr += " ";
    } else {
      let newIndex = currentIndex + n;
      newStr += alphabet[newIndex];
    }
  }
  return newStr
}

console.log(caesarCipher('ebiil tloia!', 3)) //should return hello world! but returns hellocworldc
```